# Angular 9 Universal Server Side Rendering GRPC Error

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I cannot get `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` to run correctly.

I have added Angular Universal to my project with: `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject SampleAngularApp`

`npm run build:ssr` runs and builds perfectly but `npm run serve:ssr` does not.

Here is my error when trying to server:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'
Require stack:
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/index.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js
- /Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/dist/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/grpc/index.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js',
    '/Users/mike/Desktop/Sites/SampleAngularApp/dist/server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample-angular-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-angular-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mike/.npm/_logs/2020-02-18T02_17_14_016Z-debug.log
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that installing process of `npm install -g firebase-tools` completed successfully. If the problem still persists, rebuilding grpc module should fix your problem. Please run `npm rebuild grpc`. You can also rebuild all modules by running `npm rebuild`.